# Setting ProgID in IDE

Tags: delphi, com, c++builder

I am creating a COM server using C++ Builder XE.  Its ProgID is always 'PROGRAMNAME.CLASSNAME'.

How do I change the ProgID?  I want to use 'COMPANYNAME.PROGRAMNAME.FUNCTIONALITY'.

A Delphi answer would probably suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the [GetProgID](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComObj.TComObjectFactory.GetProgID) method of the factory. Something along the lines of the following should do:

```
template <typename T>
class TMyCppComObjectFactory : public TCppComObjectFactory<T>
{
protected:
  System::UnicodeString __fastcall GetProgID()
  {
    return "Company.ProgName.Functionality";
  }
public:
  __fastcall TMyCppComObjectFactory(Comobj::TComServerObject* ComServer,
          Comobj::TComClass ComClass,
          const GUID &ClassID,
          const System::String ClassName,
          const System::String Description,
          Comobj::TClassInstancing Instancing,
          Comobj::TThreadingModel ThreadingModel) :
       TCppComObjectFactory<T>(ComServer, ComClass, ClassID,
                               ClassName, Description,
                               Instancing, ThreadingModel)
  {
  }
};
```

Then have the createFactory() of the COM Server use the derived factory.

Cheers,

Bruneau

Comment: Thanks, will test in the next while and mark answer as correct if it works.